# How to Let Delphi SelectDirectory Show Hidden Directory and Files?

Tags: delphi, directory, hidden-files

I am using Delphi XE3.

When invoking SelectionDirectory, as below:

```
Dir := '';
SelectDirectory(Dir, [], 0);
```

I find the pop up "Select Directory" dialog will not show hidden folders and files. Is there a way to show them?

THanks

Comment: Use the second overload and the browse dialog will conform with control panel settings. You can't effect the first overload, the directory list is build with FindFirst[Next] calls having only faDirectory hardcoded as Attr parameter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Does the second version of SelectDirectory support to create a directory if it is not existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old version of `SelectDirectory()` that displays a custom VCL TForm that uses a Windows 3.1 style UI and searches folders/files manually without regard to the user's settings. That version of `SelectDirectory()` does not support what you want, it will not display hidden items.

Use the newer overloaded version of `SelectDirectory()` instead. It displays a system-provided dialog for browsing folders/files that respects the user's settings. It will show hidden items if that is how the user has configured Explorer.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dir: string;
begin
  SelectDirectory('Caption', '', Dir, [], Self);
end;
```

Comment: Does the new version of SelectDirectory support to create a directory if it is not existing?

Comment: @alancc Yes, if you enable the `sdNewUI` and `sdNewFolder` flags in the `Options` parameter. [Read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.SelectDirectory).

Comment: I read the document and still have many questions, 1 "When using this syntax, SelectDirectory does not change the value of the current directory.", does "currrent directory" means the value returned by GetCurrentDirectory() Windows API? 2. Whether the second version works on different Windows platforms. I cannot find a list of supported Windows systems.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. it uses the `SHBrowseForFolder()` API internally, which is available on all Windows platforms from Win95 onward.

Comment: Thank you, Remy. I just make some more tests and write something undocumented in Delphi help here: 1. When Root is empty string '', then the dialog will show the full set of the folder tree in the computer, 2. The initial value of Directory will make that directory being selected when the dialog is shown. Correct me if there are anything wrong. Thank you very much.